# Get DefaultConstructor of Class RuntimeMethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm want to get default Constructor of Class RuntimeMethodInfo by such a code

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
Type type = assembly.GetType("System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo");
var defaultConstructor = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
```

but defaultConstructor value is null. I need default constrcutor in deserialization of json to instatnsiate object so can fill it.

Comment: Instantiate *which* object? Your *own* objects, or `RuntimeMethodInfo`? For your own objects, you don't need `RuntimeMethodInfo`. If you're really serializing method info, serialize it as the type name, method name and argument types and call `Type.GetMethod`. There is no reason at all to muck about with framework internals.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs) `RuntimeMethodInfo` is `internal sealed class` and has only `internal` constructor.
I think you don't need to create the instance of `RuntimeMethodInfo`.
You can handle deserialization of JSON by [Json.net Serializing and Deserializing](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to get and call the constructor nevertheless?

Comment: @NtFreX The `internal` constructor of this class is accepting 6 parameters, in  which are those which are internal too. So there will be needed to get them by Reflection first. I think that this is not a good idea. Deserialization of json can be handled by Json.net and attributes. I don't see any reason to create type by reflection

Comment: Ive never claimed that this is the way to work with json. I only said that i should be possible to call the constructor nevertheless because your answer makes it look like its not possible.